# Latch with no Vout

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, switches, latch

I'm working with the WiPy expansion board at 
https://github.com/wipy/wipy/blob/master/hardware/ExpansionBoard-v1.2/ExpansionBoard-v1.2_Schematics.pdf

On sheet 3, there is what appears to be a latch circuit, but the usual V(out) node of a latch isn't connected to anything. The latch connects V(battery) to GND, but I don't understand the use of it.

*Note* - If you end up looking at the GitHub page, the chip to the left of the apparent latch circuit is for battery charging and the chip to its right switches between battery and USB power sources.

[image: Apparent Latching Circuit]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand what this part of the circuit is doing. As far as I see, it's a completely self contained piece of the circuit that does nothing. Yet, it's on a professional design of the WiPy expansion board. I'm making a board based on it, so I am trying to figure out if I need to include it in my circuit or not.

Comment: To be more clear, when looking at the full schematic on GitHub I don't see a purpose for this. Since all it does is go between V(battery) and GND, I wondered if it had a common use like cleaning of the signal or making the battery turn off slowly.